# Linq query with count filter of a column

Tags: linq, filter, count, where-clause

I try to create some linq query like following.

I have a table with resource planning items. There is a column weekID and a column deployedPlanning. I would like to check if the count of deployedPlanning in each week is not higher than 40 hours. I need to add some extra where filters on the linq query below but I dont know how :( Can someone tell me how I can add these where filter on the current linq query below?

```
var resourcePlanning = new ResourcePlanningManager().Repository.Find(
                rp => rp.EmployeeID == employeeRosterPeriod.EmployeeID &&
                      rp.PlanDate >= employeeRosterPeriod.DateFrom &&
                      rp.PlanDate <= employeeRosterPeriod.DateTo).FirstOrDefault();
            if (resourcePlanning != null)
            {
               // throw excetoption. There are more than 40 hours planned in 1 or more weeks in this range!
            }
```

for example in week 40 there are in total 24 DeployedPlanned hours. This is not higher than 40 so its OK.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/513/tableresourceplanning.png/

Comment: How do `weekID` and `deployedPlanning` relate to `resourcePlanning`? Are they properties on your `rp` object? What type are the columns? I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but it sounds like:

```
var resourcePlanning = new ResourcePlanningManager().Repository.Find(
            rp => rp.EmployeeID == employeeRosterPeriod.EmployeeID &&
                  rp.PlanDate >= employeeRosterPeriod.DateFrom &&
                  rp.PlanDate <= employeeRosterPeriod.DateTo
        )
        .GroupBy(rp => rp.weekID)
        .Where(g => g.Sum(rp => rp.deployedPlanning) > 40)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```